# Changing private attributes (labels) of a Class from outside of it in Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, label, private

I made a GUI with tkinter in Python, I created a Class called "Window" to manage all the creation, functioning and changes in the GUI throughout the session.
I don't know if I am making this too complicated, but I am trying to build a method so I can only change labels from within the "Window" class, and because there is a lot of labels, I wanted to make something like the next code (this is a Minimal Reproducible Example):

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, wind):
        self.__window = wind
        self.__window.geometry("200x100")
        self.__window.title("Title")

        self.__label_1 = Label(self.__window, text="Label 1 text")
        self.__label_1.pack()

        self.__button_1 = Button(self.__window, text="Change", command=function)
        self.__button_1.pack()

    def change_label(self, label, text): #this 'label' is the name of the label I want to change
        self.label["text"] = text        #here I try to use it as the attibute's name


def function():
    myWindow.change_label("__label_1", "New text")


if __name__=='__main__':
    wind = Tk()
    myWindow = Window(wind)
    wind.mainloop()
```

The problem I am facing is obviously: AttributeError, 'Window' object has no attribute 'label'.

Is there a way to make what I'm trying to make? Send to the method the name of the label I want to change, and receive it and treat it like it is the attribute's name?

Or should I just declare the label as public and change it from outside the class "Window"?

The problem is there are a lot of labels, and I don't want them to be changed by mistake, so I wanted to "simplify" the changing process, but maybe I am making it too complicated.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: You can use an instance dictionary, for example `self.__labels = {}`, to hold the label: `self.__labels["__label_1"] = self.__label_1`.  Then use this dictionary to update the required label inside `change_label()`.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668 I am pretty new to Python so I am confused about "instance dictionary", I read something just now but I still don't get it, and I can't implement your solution. Do you mean to store all the text values of the labels in a dictionary and change directly this values? But how can I refresh the GUI so the label changes?

Comment: What I mean is an instance variable of the class with type *dictionary*, like the example in my previous comment: `self.__labels = {}`.  `self.__labels` is the instance variable and its type is *dictionary*.

Comment: **Python doesn't have private attributes** This is double-underscore name-mangling. Which is not the same as *private*, Python doesn't have any access modifiers

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `"__label_1"` is just a string used as the key in the dictionary to store or reference the label.

Comment: @acw1668 nvm misread your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the widget using string, you need to supply an unique name via `name` option.  For easier access, better use a dictionary to store the widgets using their name as the key.

Below is a modified example based on yours:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, wind):
        self.__window = wind
        self.__window.geometry("200x100")
        self.__window.title("Title")

        self.__widgets = {} # dictionary to hold the created widgets

        # use whatever "name" you want but it must be unique
        self.create(Label, text="Label 1 text", name="label_1")
        self.create(Button, text="Change", command=function, name="button_change")

    def create(self, widget, **kw):
        w = widget(self.__window, **kw)
        w.pack()
        name = kw.get("name", str(w)) # use implicitly created name if "name" option is not given
        self.__widgets[name] = w
        return name

    def change(self, name, **kw):
        self.__widgets[name].config(**kw)


def function():
    # access the widget using the unique name
    myWindow.change("label_1", text="New text", font="Arial 24 bold")


if __name__=='__main__':
    wind = Tk()
    myWindow = Window(wind)
    wind.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Two fundamental problems here. **Python doesn't have private attributes**. Python doesn't have *any* access modifiers. What you are using here is *double-underscore name-mangling*. That is **not** the same as private. It simply mangles the name to `_MyClass__my_attribute` to prevent accidental name-collisions in subclasses, it is still completely accessible from the outside:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__bar = 42
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo._Foo__bar
42
```

The idiomatic way to signal a variable that is not part of the public API is to use a *single underscore*, e.g. `self._bar = 42`, which is probably what you *should be using here*.

Now, this method will never work:

```
def change_label(self, label, text): #this 'label' is the name of the label I want to change
    self.label["text"] = text        #here I try to use it as the attibute's name
```

the way you want to it. To use a string to modify an attribute, use `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> setattr(foo, 'bar', 42)
>>> foo.bar
42
>>> getattr(foo, 'bar')
42
```